# Can user-defined autocomplete keyword description in notepad++ span multiple lines?

Tags: notepad++, xml, autocomplete

I am creating an API auto-complete XML file for my user-defined language. Can the description text assigned to the keyword be displayed as multiple lines inside the auto-complete pop-up window?

i.e.

```
<KeyWord name="sample" func="yes">
    <Overload retVal="void" descr="A description. I want this text on a new line of the np++ auto-complete pop-up window.">
        <Param name="filename string" />
    </Overload>
</KeyWord>
```

This is the result of the XML code shown above:

[image]

Is there a way to add an escaped line feed or new line character to the "descr" attribute content to place text on a new line, i.e:

(Note: this "screenshot" was manually created in Paint.NET, and was NOT produced by np++)
[image]

I have already tried the solution suggested in S.O. question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823979/how-to-have-line-breaks-in-xml-attributes
without success. Is there a way to do this?

If not, can someone tell me if is this a limitation of notepad++ or the base scintilla editing component?

Comment: This question seems more likely to be answered on StackOverflow.com. because Programmers tend to use it more than Super Users.

Comment: Doesn't `<Overload retVal="void" descr="A description.<br />I want this text on a new line of the np++ auto-complete pop-up window.">` work?  If not, the other ways of getting a line feed include `&#10;` - `&#13;` - and in some scripting languages `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting a real carriage return in the XML file by just hitting enter where you want to break the line.